# Создать алгоритм, который позволит вывести на экран (пустой, то есть только грани квадрата) квадрат из символов #. Язык python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, циклы

Создать алгоритм, который позволит вывести на экран (пустой, то есть только грани квадрата) квадрат из символов #

Можно использовать только следующие операторы print:

```
print("#",end="")
print(" ",end="")
print("") #переход на новую строку если надо.
```

размер квадрата должен вводиться с клавиатуры

Comment: И как вы думаете, как это можно сделать? Выложите вашу попытку и тогда вам смогут помочь.

Comment: В том то и дело. что я не понимаю. Думаю с помощью циклов

Comment: Давай, напиши что-нибудь, не бойся никто здесь смеяться не будет.

Comment: size = input(“введите размер:”’)

for i in range(size):
Дальше туплю)

Comment: Вот! С input ты получаешь строку, а тебе для цикла нужно число! И скорей всего тебе надо два числа - ширину и высоту.

Comment: Можно нарисовать сначала всё на бумажке. И посчитать тоже на ней.

Comment: Вот и я туплю, для квадрата конечно достаточно одного числа!

Comment: Можешь дать наводку как дальше делать?

Comment: CrazyElf уже дал наводку, нарисуй и ты увидишь, чем отличается первая и последняя строка от остальных.

Comment: Двойной цикл. Скажем, `i` и `j`. Когда надо выводить `#`? Когда `i==0`, `j==0`, `i==size-1`, `j==size-1`. Во всех остальных случаях - пробел. Ну и тело внешнего цикла завершать переходом на новую строку...

Comment: спасибо большое. Попробую так сделать и отпишусь, получилось ли)

Comment: size = input('input size:')

for i in range(size):
    i == 0
    for j in range(size):
        j == 0
    print('#' *(size-1))

Comment: Что то я не то намутил)

Comment: Попробуй сначала получить квадрат 2*2.

Comment: как его получить?

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i == 0 or j == 0 or i == n-1 or j == n-1:
            print("#",end="")
        else:
            print(" ",end="")
    print("")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Можете пожалуйста обьяснить код. Я просто хочу разобраться. Не хочу тупо скопировать и все)

Comment: @Федор Давыдов Так вы спросите, что именно непонятно, т.к. код очень простой и легко читается

Comment: if i == 0 or j == 0 or i == n-1 or j == n-1: вот эта строка непонятна

Comment: если строка первая или последняя, или если столбец первый или последний